# split a comma separated string (php + regex )

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract from this formated code:

```
name, desc,{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text, {/tag}{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text,text text{/tag}
```

into three paramters like

```
name
desc
{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text, {/tag}{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text,text text{/tag}
```

I already get something with:
 `list($field1, $field2,$field3) = preg_split('`[,]`', $param);`, but i'm stuck with this.
The problem is in the commas inside

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to all, for now I've a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not completed your approach to solving

```
$param = "name, desc,{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text, {/tag}{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text,text text{/tag}";

$s = split(',', $param);
$s[2] = implode(',', array_splice($s,2));
var_dump($s);

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [1]=>
  string(5) " desc"
  [2]=>
  string(120) "{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text, {/tag}{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text,text text{/tag}"
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Test this with: `$param = '{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text, {/tag}, name, desc';`

Comment: Why do you think that order may change?

Comment: I believe OP is just trying to avoid split the string contained in the tag. Order can be anything as `tags` may be at any place.

Comment: Ask OP :) due to 'name' and 'desc' - they are always in front, then params :)

Comment: In this case, you should use the third parameter of `explode` (`split` is deprecated since php 5.3) to limit the items to 3 (assuming there are always 3 items), no need to use `array_splice`.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can do:

```
$s = 'name, desc,{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text, {/tag}{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text,text text{/tag}';

$arr = preg_split('~{tag=.+?{/tag}(*SKIP)(*F)|\h*,\h*~', $s);

print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => desc
    [2] => {tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text, {/tag}{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text,text text{/tag}
)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI6gD9/2)

`{tag=.+?{/tag}(*SKIP)(*F)` will match all the text that is between starting and end tag and will skip that.

Answer (score -1):

You may just utilize the third argument to the `explode()` function (you need just three pieces of the string separated by comma, so just tell that to the `explode()` function!):

```
<?php
$str = 'name, desc,{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text, {/tag}{tag=name,100,type}text text,text text,text text,text text{/tag}';

$arr = array_map(
        function($v) { return trim($v); },
        explode(',', $str, 3) // <-- Actually, this statement is the only thing you need :) 
       );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

The usage of the `array_map()` function, is just for prettiness purposes only! (for `trim()`ing the values!)